# How to convert c string into Vstring vertica?

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, vertica

I'm writing a user define function for Vertica and don't know how to initialize a Vstring of Vertica from a C string (char *) . Thanks for any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following to Vertica documentation:

> You cannot create instances of `VString` or `VNumeric` yourself. You can manipulate the values of existing objects of these classes that HP Vertica passes to your UDx, and extract values from them. However, only HP Vertica can instantiate these classes.